# How can I setup a relationship using categories in WordPress?

Tags: posts, categories, query, taxonomy

I am trying to setup a relationship between a "People" post type and  a "Work" post type.

For example, I want to have a structure like this

```
Person 1
 - Work
   - Work 1 
   - Work 2
Person 2
 - Work
   - Work 3 
   - Work 4
```

How would I setup a relationship so that when a user is making a "Work" post they can associate the "work" post with a "person"?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are really looking to achieve is to relate posts from the `Person` post-type to posts from the `Work` post-type without categories.  Out of the box, WordPress doesn't have the ability to create many to many relationships across post types. To add this functionality you can use the [Posts2Posts plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/).  This plugin allows you to create many-to-many relationships between posts of any type: post, page, custom etc.

For details on how to display your connected Work and Person post types see the [Posts2Posts plugin documentation](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Basic-usage) on Github.